# Preserve cursor position when switching between buffers with :bn

Tags: vim, line, text-cursor

How do I preserve my cursor position within a line when switching buffers, with `:bn` for example?

Vim remembers which line my cursor was on, but always moves my cursor to the beginning of the line when I switch between buffers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why Vim behaves this way, but fortunately, the exact position is stored in the `'"` mark (cp. `:help 'quote`).

The following `:autocmd` will attempt to restore the cursor to that position, using the `` g` `` command:

```
:autocmd BufEnter * silent! normal! g`"
```

*Note:* You can append positioning commands like `zz` (which positions the current line in the center of the window) or `zv` (which opens any folds) after the `` g` ``.

Comment: Awesome. I added this autocmd to my vimrc and it works exactly as I expected.

Comment: @LondonRob, append `zz` like so `autocmd BufEnter * silent! normal! g\`"zz`

Answer (score 9):

How about

[Vim cursor jumps to beginning of the line after buffer switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292742/vim-cursor-jumps-to-beginning-of-the-line-after-buffer-switch)

TL;DR

```
:set nostartofline
```

For me `` g`" `` messes with my quickfix position.

Comment: This is the actual best solution as this behavior is documented in :h startofline : "In case of buffer changing commands the cursor is placed at the column where it was the last time the buffer was edited". Other solutions seem to be dirty hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function in my ~/.vimrc that saves the datetime near the top of the file upon saves (if there is a "last modified" string near the top of the file):

```
function! LastModified()
  if &modified
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let n = min([250, line("$")])
    :silent keepjumps exe '1,' . n . 's/^\(.*L\)ast.modified.*:.*/\1ast modified: ' . strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z (PST)') . '/e'
    call histdel('search', -1)
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
  endif
endfun
autocmd BufWritePre * call LastModified()
## Ref [1], [2]
```

That works fine; however, my cursor was jumping lines (failing to retain the line position / cursor position) when switching buffers in a vertical split.

```sh
autocmd BufEnter * silent! normal! g`"
```

(suggested in another answer in this thread) had no effect, but this (Ref [3]) solved that problem:

```
" Save current view settings on a per-window, per-buffer basis.
function! AutoSaveWinView()
    if !exists("w:SavedBufView")
        let w:SavedBufView = {}
    endif
    let w:SavedBufView[bufnr("%")] = winsaveview()
endfunction

" Restore current view settings.
function! AutoRestoreWinView()
    let buf = bufnr("%")
    if exists("w:SavedBufView") && has_key(w:SavedBufView, buf)
        let v = winsaveview()
        let atStartOfFile = v.lnum == 1 && v.col == 0
        if atStartOfFile && !&diff
            call winrestview(w:SavedBufView[buf])
        endif
        unlet w:SavedBufView[buf]
    endif
endfunction

" When switching buffers, preserve window view.
if v:version >= 700
    autocmd BufLeave * call AutoSaveWinView()
    autocmd BufEnter * call AutoRestoreWinView()
endif
```

---

Aside: to make it somewhat easier to follow edits in either split, in Normal mode press `zz` to vertically center the current line (Ref [4]).

---

[1] https://docwhat.org/vim-preserve-your-cursor-and-window-state
[2] http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time
[3] https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_scrolling_when_switch_buffers
[4] https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Make_search_results_appear_in_the_middle_of_the_screen